# Failed to load application: No module named

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, runtime-error, python-import

I'm having difficulty launching a twisted python script outside its working directory. When I try, I receive the following error:

```
exceptions.ImportError: No module named mining
```

My understanding is that if I add the module's path to sys.path, then it should be able to find it. For example, I have added:

```
sys.path.append("/root/stratum-mining/mining")
```

I have also tried changing the working directory of the script using

```
os.chdir('/root/stratum-mining')
```

I've verified that the module's path is in sys.path, but as soon as it gets to "import mining" it fails.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Python packages, you have to add the directory containing the package directory to `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path`, not the package directory itself, so changing...

```
sys.path.append("/root/stratum-mining/mining")
```

...to...

```
sys.path.append("/root/stratum-mining")
```

...should allow you to `import mining` as long as `/root/stratum-mining/mining` is accessible, and contains a file named `__init__.py`.

Comment: Thanks! That really was simple!